# How to direct to set specific folder in Music App and can se the list of songs in detail format? mac os 14.1.2

Tags: music-management, macos-sonoma

HoI want to run songs in list from specific folder, tried Add folder but when I see in Music App.

1. it show tile mode
2. it might copy in other folder also ( which I can stopt to do so)

but issue is I cant see list completely, in which location we can see the list ? in history is how other songs too.

macOS Sonoma 14.1.2